# How to avoid barchart annotations overlapping with left y axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[bar chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bERKN.png)

I am making a series of graphs like this. Negative values have annotations to the left, and positive values have annotations to the right. I would like to keep it this way, but the negative annotations almost always collide with the y axis. Negative values vary from chart to chart, so I am trying to figure out a solution that will work for all of these. Here is the code I used for annotations if that helps. Thank you so much!

```
rects = ax.patches

# For each bar: Place a label
for rect in rects:
    # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
    x_value = rect.get_width()
    y_value = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2

    # Number of points between bar and label. Change to your liking.
    space = 5
    # Vertical alignment for positive values
    ha = 'left'

    # If value of bar is negative: Place label left of bar
    if x_value < 0:
        # Invert space to place label to the left
        space *= -1
        # Horizontally align label at right
        ha = 'right'

    
    label = "$ " + str('{:,}'.format(x_value))


    # Create annotation
    plt.annotate(
        label,  # Use `label` as label
        (x_value, y_value),  # Place label at end of the bar
        xytext=(space, 0),  # Horizontally shift label by `space`
        textcoords="offset points",  # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
        va='center',  # Vertically center label
        ha=ha)  # Horizontally align label differently for
    # positive and negative values.
```

Comment: if possible, please make your question reproducible with sample data.

Comment: Maybe set your `xlim` to fit this data?

Comment: Or you could set wider margins. E.g. `plt.margins(x=0.2)` to add a margin of 20% of the occupied width.